# can i perform cascaded delete using foreign key constraints in MySql 3.0?

Tags: mysql

can i perform cascaded delete using foreign key constraints in MySql 3.0  ?

Comment: Why would you like to use a death dino as a database? Not even version 5.0 is supported anymore!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) mention,

> ON DELETE CASCADE is supported
>   starting from MySQL 3.23.50

so your 3.0 is just too old for it.